Repetitive result issue with Azure Speech Recognition in .NET
I'm building a live mic speech-to-text transcription on Azure using .NET. However, a single sentence results in multiple repetitive sentences. I need help identifying the issue that causes repetitive output. If I speak in the mic saying:
"Hello my name is John",
the code produces the following output:
"Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John Hello my name is John"
What I want is live transcription of a sentence that appears once without repetition, exactly how it works on Azure's Speech Studio - Real-time speech to text.
Here's my code:
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using [ ].Hubs;
using [ ].Services;
using [ ].Data;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5001");
                webBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddControllers();
                    services.AddSignalR();

                    // Configure CORS
                    services.AddCors(options =>
                    {
                        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                        {
                            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                                   .AllowCredentials();
                        });
                    });

                    services.AddSingleton<SpeechService>();
                    services.AddSingleton<TranscriptionService>();

                    // Add DbContext and hosted service
                    services.AddDbContext<CosmosDbContext>();
                    services.AddHostedService<CosmosDbTestService>();
                })
                .Configure((context, app) =>
                {
                    if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    }

                    // Enable CORS
                    app.UseCors();

                    app.UseRouting();

                    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                    {
                        endpoints.MapControllers();
                        endpoints.MapHub<TranscriptionHub>("/transcriptionHub");
                    });
                });
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole();
            });
}

SpeechService.cs (/Service):
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

namespace [ ].Services
{
    public class SpeechService
    {
        private readonly SpeechRecognizer _speechRecognizer;
        private bool isRecognizing = false;
        public event Action<string>? OnRecognizing;
        public event Action<string>? OnRecognized;

        public SpeechService()
        {
            var subscriptionKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SPEECH_KEY");
            var region = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SPEECH_REGION");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subscriptionKey) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(region))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Azure Speech Service key and region must be provided via environment variables.");
            }

            var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);
            speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "de-DE";
            speechConfig.EnableDictation(); // Enable dictation mode for explicit punctuation

            var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
            _speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

            _speechRecognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech)
                {
                    OnRecognizing?.Invoke(e.Result.Text);
                }
            };

            _speechRecognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                {
                    OnRecognized?.Invoke(e.Result.Text);
                }
            };

            _speechRecognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
            {
                isRecognizing = false;
                Console.WriteLine($"Recognition canceled: {e.Reason}, {e.ErrorDetails}");
            };

            _speechRecognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
            {
                isRecognizing = false;
                Console.WriteLine($"Session stopped: {e.SessionId}");
            };
        }

        public async Task StartRecognitionAsync()
        {
            if (!isRecognizing)
            {
                isRecognizing = true;
                await _speechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        public async Task StopRecognitionAsync()
        {
            if (isRecognizing)
            {
                await _speechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                isRecognizing = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

TranscriptionService.cs (/Service):
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using [ ].Hubs;

namespace [ ].Services
{
    public class TranscriptionService
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<TranscriptionHub> _hubContext;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _connections = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public TranscriptionService(IHubContext<TranscriptionHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public void AddConnection(string connectionId)
        {
            _connections[connectionId] = connectionId;
        }

        public void RemoveConnection(string connectionId)
        {
            _connections.TryRemove(connectionId, out _);
        }

        public async Task BroadcastRecognizing(string text)
        {
            foreach (var connectionId in _connections.Keys)
            {
                await _hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveRecognizing", text);
            }
        }

        public async Task BroadcastRecognized(string text)
        {
            foreach (var connectionId in _connections.Keys)
            {
                await _hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveRecognized", text);
            }
        }
    }
}

TranscriptionHub.cs (/Hub):
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using [ ].Services;

namespace [ ].Hubs
{
    public class TranscriptionHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly SpeechService _speechService;
        private readonly TranscriptionService _transcriptionService;

        public TranscriptionHub(SpeechService speechService, TranscriptionService transcriptionService)
        {
            _speechService = speechService;
            _transcriptionService = transcriptionService;
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            _transcriptionService.AddConnection(Context.ConnectionId);
            _speechService.OnRecognizing += HandleRecognizing;
            _speechService.OnRecognized += HandleRecognized;
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            _transcriptionService.RemoveConnection(Context.ConnectionId);
            _speechService.OnRecognizing -= HandleRecognizing;
            _speechService.OnRecognized -= HandleRecognized;
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        private async void HandleRecognizing(string text)
        {
            await _transcriptionService.BroadcastRecognizing(text);
        }

        private async void HandleRecognized(string text)
        {
            await _transcriptionService.BroadcastRecognized(text);
        }

        public async Task StartTranscription()
        {
            await _speechService.StartRecognitionAsync();
        }

        public async Task StopTranscription()
        {
            await _speechService.StopRecognitionAsync();
        }
    }
}


The implication is that an "event handler" is getting called more than once (and that possibly you've hooked a handler up more than once). So I would see "if" and what event handler is firing more than once; and why (using Debug.Asserts and / or Writes, for example)

The issue is  due to the way continuous recognition is handled in the Azure Cognitive Services Speech SDK. Continuous recognition is designed to provide interim results (partially recognized phrases) and final results (fully recognized phrases). This can sometimes lead to what seems like repetitive output if not handled properly.
You are handling both interim and final results in the same way, which causes the repeated output. To solve this, you should handle the interim results (Recognizing event) separately from the final results (Recognized event).
Here’s how you can modify your code to handle the events correctly:

I used this links for  Speech to text
and real time speech to text


using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourNamespace.Services
{
    public class SpeechService
    {
        private readonly SpeechRecognizer _speechRecognizer;
        private bool isRecognizing = false;
        private string lastRecognizedText = string.Empty;
        public event Action<string>? OnRecognizing;
        public event Action<string>? OnRecognized;

        public SpeechService()
        {
            var subscriptionKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SPEECH_KEY");
            var region = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SPEECH_REGION");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subscriptionKey) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(region))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Azure Speech Service key and region must be provided via environment variables.");
            }

            var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);
            speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "de-DE";//"en-US"
            speechConfig.EnableDictation(); 

            var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
            _speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

    
            speechConfig.RequestWordLevelTimestamps();

            _speechRecognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech)
                {
                    OnRecognizing?.Invoke(e.Result.Text);
                    Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING: {e.Result.Text}");
                    //Console.WriteLine($"Offset in Ticks: {e.Result.OffsetInTicks}");
                   // Console.WriteLine($"Duration in Ticks: {e.Result.Duration.Ticks}");
                }
            };

            _speechRecognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech && !string.Equals(e.Result.Text, lastRecognizedText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    lastRecognizedText = e.Result.Text;
                    OnRecognized?.Invoke(e.Result.Text);
                    Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                 //   Console.WriteLine($"Offset in Ticks: {e.Result.OffsetInTicks}");
                   // Console.WriteLine($"Duration in Ticks: {e.Result.Duration.Ticks}");

                    var detailedResults = e.Result.Best();
                    if (detailedResults != null && detailedResults.Any())
                    {
                        var bestResults = detailedResults.First();
                        Console.WriteLine($"\tConfidence: {bestResults.Confidence}\n\tText: {bestResults.Text}\n\tLexicalForm: {bestResults.LexicalForm}\n\tNormalizedForm: {bestResults.NormalizedForm}\n\tMaskedNormalizedForm: {bestResults.MaskedNormalizedForm}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"\tWord-level timing:");
                        Console.WriteLine($"\t\tWord | Offset | Duration");
                        Console.WriteLine($"\t\t----- | ----- | ----- ");

                        foreach (var word in bestResults.Words)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{word.Word} | {word.Offset} | {word.Duration}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            _speechRecognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
            {
                isRecognizing = false;
                Console.WriteLine($"Recognition canceled: {e.Reason}, {e.ErrorDetails}");
            };

            _speechRecognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
            {
                isRecognizing = false;
                Console.WriteLine($"Session stopped: {e.SessionId}");
            };
        }

        public async Task StartRecognitionAsync()
        {
            if (!isRecognizing)
            {
                isRecognizing = true;
                await _speechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        public async Task StopRecognitionAsync()
        {
            if (isRecognizing)
            {
                await _speechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                isRecognizing = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:

